# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential issue

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-assembly, credentials, sqlconnection

I have some problems with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential class. I try to create an object in powershell by using this

```
cls;
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data");
$creds = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential;
```

But I get this error message

```
New-Object : Конструктор не найден. Не удается найти соответствующий    конструкто
р для типа System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential.
строка:3 знак:10
+ $creds = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential;
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :    CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.C 
   ommands.NewObjectCommand
```

The translation of this error message is as follows:

*The constructor could not be found. Unable to find the appropriate constructor for type.*

I read technet and found out, that System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential class is contained in System.Data (System.Data.dll).

But I tried to load this assembly as you see from previous example. I use Windows 7, PowerShell 4.0. I have .NET Frameworks 4.6.1 installed. I'll really appreciate any help.

I've tried to use the tip GodEater offered me, but still get an error message

```
cls;

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data");

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=192.168.1.220,1433;Database=Archimed;";
$creds = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential`
((Read-Host -AsSecureString), (Read-Host -AsSecureString));
$SqlConnection.Credential = $creds;

$SqlConnection.Open();
$SqlConnection.Close();
```

Error message is like this

```
New-Object : Не удается найти тип [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential]: убедит
есь в том, что сборка, содержащая этот тип, загружена.
строка:7 знак:10
+ $creds = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential`
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewOb 
   jectCommand

System.Security.SecureString
System.Security.SecureString
Исключение при вызове "Open" с "0" аргументами: "Ошибка входа пользователя ""."
строка:11 знак:1
+ $SqlConnection.Open();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Translations is as follows:

*Can not find the type of [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential]: make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded*

*Exception when calling the "Open" from the "0" argument: "Login failed for user ''."*

I used sa and 1 for the user and pass.

Comment: The constructor doesn't take secure strings, it takes plaintext.

Comment: Also - your second attempt has failed because you didn't load the assembly the second time around.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but just in case someone stumbles across it.

The previous answer was almost correct.  You do need to pass the user id and and password to the constructor, but the password must be a secure string.

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force "ThePassword"
$creds = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential('UserName', $SecurePassword)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the constructor for that type requires a user id and password - you can't create it without specifying them - so you'd need to call it like this :

```
$creds = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential('UserName','Password')
```

Obviously replacing those with your actual username and password.